# How can the timestamp value being returned from the jquery ajax call be converted from {ts 'xxxx-xx-xx xx:xx:xx'} style to string format

Tags: jquery, ajax, format, timestamp

The variable **returnMsg** comes back as {ts '2015-03-04 09:10:00'} 
However I need to represent data returned in string format "2015/03/04 09:10"

```
        var myDate;
        $.ajax({
            url: "../DateFunctions.cfc",
            type:"POST",
            cache: false,
            dataType: "text",
            async:false,
            data: {method: "AddBusinessDays",
                   daysToAdd: DaysDue,
                   date: StartDate

            },
            success: function(returnMsg)
                     {
                        try
                        {
                          var obj = new Date(returnMsg);
                          myDate = obj;           
                        }
                        catch(e)
                        {
                          alert('AddBusinessDays Error parsing returnMsg');
                        }
                     },
            error: function(httpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown)
                   {
                        alert("AddBusinessDays status=" + textStatus + ",error=" + errorThrown);
                   }
         });

        return myDate;
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use a regular expression to extract the date from the string.

```
var match = returnMsg.match(/\{ts '(.*)'\}/);
var myDate = new Date(match[1]);
```